# Should I split my tables into different tables when all of the data is dependant on the primary key?

Tags: denormalization

For my assignment I have to make a database for my licensing application. I have 12 columns and one column is for the license key. All other columns are data that is related to the license key. The license key is always different. I'm getting told that it's better to split the table into more tables to remove redundant data.
The table is as follows:

> license_code
>   product_amount
>   product_limit
>   product_name
>   start_date
>   end_date
>   first_registration_date
>   most_recent_check_date
>   registration_end_date
>   hardware_id
>   IP
>   status

Currently I have it split into this:

Table: License

> license_code*
>   product_id*
>   start_date
>   end_date
>   first_registration_date
>   most_recent_check_date
>   registration_end_date
>   product_amount
>   product_limit
>   hardware_id
>   IP
>   status

Table: Product

> product_id*
>   product_name

I'm really thinking that it's unnecessary to split it because all the data is dependant on the license_code column anyway. Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

**EDIT: explaination of how it's used**

A license key/code is basically a unique string. To use a product (software program), a license key has to be used. A product can be activated with multiple license keys, person 1 can use code X to activate product Y, person 2 can use code Z to activate product Y. So a license key can activate multiple instances of a product but it can only be used for a single product.

I hope I'm clearer with this explaination.

Comment: Indirectly dependent is not dependent.  Can different license codes with the same product IDs have different product names?  If not then product name is _not_ dependent on the license code.  Go read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization and try to understand the basic normal forms, especially third normal form.

Comment: Does the value of `product_name` repeat across different `licence_code`s? If yes then you should normalize that out to a separate table as you have done. And where did the `product_amount` and `product_limit` fields go?

Comment: @JoelBrown, you got a valid point there. so I should have a table Product. Can all other columns stay in one table, as it is directly dependant on the license_code?

Comment: @srutzky woops they should go in the License table, edited.

Comment: Can a hardware_id show up for more than one licence_code? Is the IP unique to each hardware_id? If yes, then that should also be broken out, kinda like you have done, but the PK on the lookup table would hardware_id and you wouldn't have the licence_code field.

Comment: @srutzky hardware_id should be unique just like the license_code, hardware_id is the id of you motherboard or HDD. IP is unique to each license_code.

Comment: If hardware_id and IP can only ever show up once in the table, then they should remain in the main table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29035/discussion-between-denny-and-srutzky).

Comment: Do not think that you must include the `product_id` in the primary key of the `license` table. This means that if you link another `product` to the `license` that you need to copy the license data into this new relation. Either you take it out of the `license` primary key or you should name it something like `license_product` and move the fields that depend only on the `license_id` to a 'new' table `license`.

Comment: Simple question.  Does product_name repeat?

Comment: @Frisbee Yes, it can repeat, ex: person1 has a license key for productX, but person2 can also have a license key for productX. The license keys are not the same but the product name can be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we are short on a little bit of information such as what exactly the license is for and how it is to be used. For example, do all products have exactly one license? Can licenses contain multiple products? As the term license is used, I would imagine that each individual would have their own license to use the product (thus one to many relationship). With that scenario, I will assume that a license is only valid for one product and that several licenses can reference a single a product (a one-to-many relationship).

So to satisfy that requirement, we will need two tables. One for the products, and one for the licenses. The product table would contain all product information such as:

```
Products
-----------
ProductID
Name,
Description,
Price,
(etc)

Licenses
--------
LicenseID,
ProductID,
StartDate,
EndDate,
Amount, -- I believe this is to represent how many individual licenses of this one is used
Limit,  -- And this is to represent how many people can use this current license
(etc)
```

With this, we have a few benefits. Now, we can license out an individual product to multiple people (again, I am assuming the product is something like software) and we can now change licenses with out affecting the product and if we need to make changes to the product, all the licenses will automatically be updated. A good example of this is the changing of a product description. If products were stored with the licenses, we would have to change all the licenses that used that same product. That's not good and prone to having inconsistent data.

If I am off base, feel free to let me know. As you can see, I made quite a few assumptions.

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer! Most of you assumptions are correct, I have added a explaination of how it's supposed to be used. I will keep your information in mind.